# How can the temporary update directory be changed?

Tags: updates, directory, upgrade

When a plugin, theme, or even WordPress itself are updated, it downloads and saves the files (`.zip`, extracted files, etc.) to `wp-content\upgrade`. This is not always desirable.

For example, I run a portable version of WordPress from a flash-drive, so I don’t want it using the flash-drive for temp files. I would prefer it to put temporary files in the system’s temporary directory.

I already changed the temporary (upload) directory in `php.ini` as so:

```
upload_tmp_dir = ${Temp}
```

This works for regular PHP scripts, and while I’ve seen [a couple](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/any-way-to-change-temporary-download-folders) [of pages](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://forum.wpde.org/installation/76016-tmpdir-und-wp_temp_dir-meist-ueberfluessig.html) which seem to indicate that WordPress (3.0+) should use the default (upload? download?) temporary directory, it is ignoring it and still putting the temporary files in `wp-content\upgrade`.

How can this be changed?

Answer (score 2):

Impossible. The path is hard coded in many places (`wp-admin/includes/update-core.php` for example).

I think this is worth a Trac ticket, if there isn’t one already. We can move the directories for plugins, themes and mu-plugins. This is the last thing why we need a wp-content directory at all.

#### Update

There was a short discussion in [ticket #25153](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25153). The result is a *wontfix*, because the `upgrade` directory enforces the existence of a `wp-content` directory (whatever its name is in your setup), and *that* should be kept in case the core needs to add further directories here later, for example `wp-content/libraries/`.

You can set the `upload` directory and the `wp-content` directory to the same physical directory [via `wp-config.php` constants](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder). This should be clean enough for time being.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I checked and could not find anything about it in either Trac or WordPress Ideas, so I submitted [the ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25153).

Comment: @Synetech I made an update to my answer and summarized the discussion from your ticket.

Comment: Argh. They sound a lot like the Chrome developers; too narrow-minded about different configurations and uses and too obstinate to make any changes they don’t consider useful for themselves. I’m currently weaning off of Chrome, but I think I can continue with WordPress—though this is the sort of thing that leads to modifying core or forking altogether. I looked at your suggestion, but `wp-content` contains a lot of necessary files, and I don’t know what `uploads` is for but `upgrade` is the one where it puts the temporary files (besides, it has to be relative, so it must be on the same drive).