# Why is Wordpress upgrade process not using WP_TEMP_DIR?

Tags: wp-config, upgrade, filesystem, wp-filesystem

I am setting up a special Wordpress deployment that has all dynamically uploaded and modified files stored in a single location.

Wordpress provides constants that allow to modify location of all but one folder within `wp-content`. The exception is `wp-content/upgrade`.

Is there a reason why this folder does not have a constant? Why doesn't the folder generate within `WP_TEMP_DIR`? It seems to me that the upgrade files belong there, since they are temporary by nature.

Is there a way to override location of `wp-content/upgrade` in relation to `wp-content`?

Comment: This answer to a similiar question also answers mine: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/111722/230781  I marked my question as a duplicate, but perhaps it needs more people to count. In summary: the folder is hardcoded intentionally to force existance of the parent folder.